# SELECT statement returning count rather than result set with ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

When I perform the following query using

```
Post.connection.execute "SELECT id FROM posts WHERE id in ('123')"    # => 0
```

I get the result `0` instead of an empty record set `[]` like I would expect

**Why could this be happening???**

I get a normal result set if I switch to

```
Post.find_by_sql "SELECT id FROM posts WHERE id in ('123')"    # => []
```